# What is causing this Run-time '9' error when using 2 arrays to fill a 2 column listbox?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am trying to fill a Listbox (SkuList) which has two columns, with help of 2 arrays that represent two columns. One of the columns is not always in the same place, so I have to do it like this to my knowledge. I have made the following code:

```
'WrkBook is a Textbox on the Userform
'SkuList is a Listbox on the Userform
Dim wrk As String
Me.WrkBook.Value = ThisWorkbook.Name
wrk = WrkBook.Value
Dim Esh As Worksheet
Set Esh = Workbooks(wrk).Sheets("Resultaat")

Dim hFind As Range, hCol As Long, hRow As Long, skuArr() As Variant, NLArr() As Variant, iA As Long
Set hFind = Esh.Range("A1", Esh.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Find("producttitel")
If Not hFind Is Nothing Then
    hCol = hFind.Column
    hRow = Esh.Range("A2").End(xlDown).row
    skuArr = Esh.Range("A2", Esh.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value
    NLArr = Esh.Range(Esh.Cells(2, hCol), Esh.Cells(hRow, hCol)).Value
    For iA = LBound(skuArr) To UBound(skuArr)
        With Me.SkuList
            .AddItem
            .List(iA, 0) = skuArr(iA)
            .List(iA, 1) = NLArr(iA)
        End With
    Next iA
End If
```

The problem is that when I try to run this code, I get "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" on the line `.List(iA, 0) = skuArr(iA)`

I am not sure how to solve this problem, so could somebody please help?

Comment: They are 2D arrays, so you need: `skuArr(iA, 1)` and similarly for the other array.

Comment: That seems to have fixed the Run-time error '9'! But now I get 
"Run-time error '381': Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index."

Comment: I seem to have found the solution: I changed iA to a Variant (probably didn't do much), and I changed ```.List(iA, 0)``` to ```.List(iA - 1, 0)```, and now it seems to work.